# Android - Service with Application lifecycle

Tags: android, service, android-activity, aidl

I am trying to create a `Service`for my application which will negotiate Bluetooth connections and data. I want this service's lifecycle to start and end with the `Application`, but still be able to have specific `Activities` listen for events that occur within this service (in addition an `Activty` should be able to call specific methods of the `Service` to write data or query connection state).

I started by creating AIDL interfaces for my callbacks and service, but I can't figure out exactly what I'm doing.

How is the best way to go about this? Thanks.

**EDIT**: To be clear, I do not specifically need (or want) more than one process for my application. Right now I don't have more than one; I'm just using AIDL because it is [the only way I know of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463175/how-to-have-android-service-communicate-with-activity) for a `Service` to communicate with an `Activity`.

Comment: It's not the only way by the way. You may go with extending Binder. It's the only way if you need IPC across different applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted an answer to a similar topic as this earlier today.

[Restful API service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service/3197456#3197456)

I think the best way is to do an IntentService, and have your activity as a ResultReceiver, so  when your service is done with some work it sends a message back to the activity.

Comment: UI thread just should do UI tasks. It shouldn't do other background tasks.