# Communication between Android Services and Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, localbroadcastmanager

[image: see architecture]

I want to develop an Android App with three activities and two services.

The first Service, named **WebClientService**, calls a REST API every 30 seconds, using an Handler, and has to notify the active Activity with the result.
It also has to notify a second Service, named **DatabaseService**, in order to update a local DB.

The Database Service will be called just once *onCreate* of the activity (in case of app crash and restart) and just once at *onRestart* (in this way we have data to show in case there were connectivity issues). The activities will then keep themselves updated thanks to the WebClientService that notifies the "alive" activity every 30 seconds.

Questions are:

- What's the best way to notify for an update both the active activity and the background DatabaseService? 
  My idea is to use *sendBroadcast()* within WebClientService and a *[BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)* in every activity and within the DatabaseService, is it the right approach?
- Should I use the same approach for the communication between AllMeetingRoomActivity and DatabaseService or should I use a [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: 
DatabaseService won't be a background service anymore but just a shared instance of the db layer between WebClientService and the activities.

So question now is: is it a good approach to just write my 30 seconds updates to the local db and **allow the activities to update themselves every few seconds simply reading from the local db**? 
Would that affect the **performance** too much?

**Context:**

Follows what I've implemented so far but using SettableFutures and thus needs to be re-implemented using Services and Broadcasts once I've clear how to make them communicate effectively:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {               

    private TextView meetingsTextView;
    private EditText mEdit, editSubject;

    private final ConnectorInitializer clientInitializer = new ConnectorInitializer();
    private AppConnector genericClient; // can use OutlookClient or a test client to talk with a mock server

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // initializes client based on the settings in "config.json"
        genericClient = clientInitializer.create(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        meetingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NowMeeting);
        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editSubject   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSubject);

        Futures.addCallback(genericClient.logon(this, scopes), new FutureCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                Log.d("APP", "-- Logged in. --");

                databaseConnector.synchronouslyGetBackupFromLocalDatabase() // FUTURE
                // callback here
                // onSuccess, onFailure

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.e("\n ~~~~>> logon \n", t.getMessage());
                meetingsTextView.setText(R.string.Login_Failed);
            }
        });

    }

    /** At the moment the UI is not updated automatically every 30 seconds
    *   but manually using a refresh button
    */
    public void getBookings(@SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters") View view){

        Log.d("APP", "Retrieve button clicked: "+(DateTime.now())+". Calling async getCalendar.");
        meetingsTextView.setText(R.string.retrieving_events);

        try{
            Futures.addCallback( genericClient.getCalendarEvents(), new FutureCallback<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final String resultCalendars) {

                    Log.d("APP", "Success. Result: "+resultCalendars);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Log.d("APP", "Calendars SUCCESSFULLY retrieved.");
                            String meetingsRetrieved = getString(R.string.calendar)+resultCalendars;
                            meetingsTextView.setText(meetingsRetrieved);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                    databaseConnector.asyncUpdateLocalDbWithResults(); // FUTURE
                    // callback here
                    // onSuccess, onFailure

               }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Throwable t) {
                    Log.e( "APP", "Calendar error. Cause: "+t.getLocalizedMessage() );
                    String retrieveError = "Retrieve error. \n\n\n"+t.getLocalizedMessage();
                    meetingsTextView.setText(retrieveError);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }catch(Exception ex){    
            Log.e("APP","Something went wrong in your code. Cause:"+ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain with some psedou code?

Comment: I'm so confuse because I don't know what you really want to do

Comment: @Slim_user71169 I've rephrased the question and attached a skinny diagram to illustrate the desired architecture. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27652660/4317945

Comment: From the description it seems to be that your DatabaseService should instead be a ContentProvider - then you can use ContentObservers and other existing APIs instead of trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: try to use OttoBus library, which is light weight event bus system for android by Squre..
http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: Broadcast receivers or ResultReceiver will be the best options to achieve this

Comment: @ankitaggarwal About [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) I read "the connection will break if your process goes away for any reason". Does BrodcastReceiver fit best then? My service will have to be always running on working hours. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your approach is ok with `BroadCastReceiver`. However, `BroadCastReceiver` should be used for a global purpose (like communicating between 2 applications). If you intend to use `BroadCastReceiver` for your app only, I prefer using [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) instead. Using `LocalBroadcastManager` is faster and more security when it can be caught only by your app.

There's another way to communicate between your `activity`s and your `service`s is using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). It will be much easier than using `BroadCastReceiver` (especially in passing data between them).

**Update:** About your update question:

1. is it a good approach to just write my 30 seconds updates to the local db and allow the activities to update themselves every few seconds simply reading from the local db? --> Of course NO. You should let your activities update themselves when they need. When you update your local db, you should know that is there any changes or not. If there is any change, use `LocalBroadcastmanager` to notify your activity to update.
2. Would that affect the performance too much? --> Yes, that do. The db connection will take time to execute and it will block your UI in some cases. in that case, you should use a thread with `ExecutorService` for each `execute` (insert, update...). One more thing to consider is updating that frequently will drain your phone battery very, very fast.

Comment: I've updated the question and added a bounty. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks mate, very useful!

Comment: At this point I'm wondering if I should just send the data I need to update the activities with inside the LocalBrodcastManager notifications and scratch the db layer. I don't need that data to be "crash resistant" since my source of truth is the Outlook backend. Anyhow I need WebClientService to be a background service because it will also send the current user data to an internal service in order to share it with other devices using different users and I don't want that shared data to be outdated if the user is using some other activity (eg. settings, etc). You think it's a good approach? TA

Comment: @GaSacchi You can update your activity with `LocalBroadCastReceiver`. However, I dont think calling `restful` service every 30s is a good idea. It will drain your battery really fast, even faster than you think. As my opinion, 1 good approach for sync data between multiple devices is:
option 1. Using sessions (for 1 online device at a time)
option 2. Using Google cloud messaging to notify the device to update when it need instead of updating every 30s.

Comment: Well the device will be in a wall and plugged in to power supply so the battery consumption is not a problem..

Comment: I've chosen your answer for its completeness.

Answer (score 10):

#### Best option ever:

Use `LocalBroadcastManager`. More reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

**MyService.java:**

```
private LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;
private final String SERVICE_RESULT = "com.service.result";
private final String SERVICE_MESSAGE = "com.service.message";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

   // Other stuff

   localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
}
```

Add below method in service, whenever you want to update data from service to Activity, call method by passing `Arguments`.

```
private void sendResult(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SERVICE_RESULT);
    if(message != null)
        intent.putExtra(SERVICE_MESSAGE, message);
    localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String s = intent.getStringExtra(MyService.SERVICE_MESSAGE);
            // do something here.
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((broadcastReceiver), 
        new IntentFilter(MyService.SERVICE_RESULT));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: SERVICE_MESSAGE could also be a DTO object that I pass around activities, right? Thanks

Comment: And for secutity concerns.. other apps won't be able to get those broadcasted intents sent using LocalBroadcasManager, right?
Thanks again

Comment: @GaSacchi, Yes, you can pass any object with this one and for security it rely only within application, so other apps doesnt able to get it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've chosen Kingfisher Phuoc's answer for its completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the services to the activities and update your UI.
Or you can use libraries like Otto or EventBus to create a publisher/subscriber dependency and notify your activities everytime your services publish an update of information.

Answer (score 1):

Use event bus for this communication. EventBus allows publish-subscribe-style communication between components without requiring the components to explicitly register with one another (and thus be aware of each other). It is designed exclusively to replace traditional Java in-process event distribution using explicit registration.

There are a lot of them:

http://square.github.io/otto/

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

This is an example of Otto usage:

```
Bus bus = new Bus();

bus.post(new AnswerAvailableEvent(42));

@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(AnswerAvailableEvent event) {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow!
}

bus.register(this); // In order to receive events, a class instance needs to register with the bus.
```

To post from any thread (main or background), in you case a Service and receive events on the main thread:

```
public class MainThreadBus extends Bus {
  private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

  @Override
  public void post(final Object event) {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
      super.post(event);
    } else {
      mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          MainThreadBus.super.post(event);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```