# Hide MainActiviy when DialogActivity starts

Tags: java, android

I use firebird cloud messaging to receive data in the background, then a dialog (new Activity with `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` as style) will appear. My problem is that the surface of the MainActivity is displayed every time in the background. Is it possible to hide MainActivity without terminating it? Someone has perhaps an idea?

When i set in the Manifest at the MainActivity the value
`android:noHistory="true"`
i looks good, but the notification is then in the app history. this looks bad

I mean when the activity is in Background that the MainActivity is still visible

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: set background color in style by defying it in style.xml

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the MainActivity still opens in background. It should stay in the background.

Comment: offcourse  mainactivity will be in the background.

Comment: Do not have my pc atm but did something similar (somewhat like the popup some sms applications generate) with a transparent background. Mine shows on top of home or lock screen if application is in background. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an Activity as a dialog, your MainActivity remains in the Activity Stack in a paused state. However, even if you make the Dialog Activity full-screen, it is not guaranteed that MainActivity will be kept alive. The OS can kill the activity anytime if it needs memory for other processes. [This is stated on the Activity reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Instead you could try one of these alternative solutions:

1. Use a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog) instead of a new Activity
2. Use regular Fragments, adding the fragment at runtime, allowing the user to switch between the dialog Fragment and the Main fragment.
3. Use a FrameLayout, to show/hide the dialog UI inside the same Main Activity layout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i was not able to start the DialogFragment from the Service class because is have no Access to the Displaymanager. This seems to work only from an Activity

Comment: You didn't mention a Service class before. If you mean an Android Service, then what's left for you is to [communicate between the Service and the Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525508/communication-between-android-services-and-activities) to trigger the display of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think are looking for this method

```
    /* When {@link #FLAG_DIM_BEHIND} is set, this is the amount of dimming
     * to apply.  Range is from 1.0 for completely opaque to 0.0 for no
     * dim.
     */
```

> dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().dimAmount = 1f;