# How to perform an action when a service stops?

Tags: android, service

I am developing an application where I start a background service and I want my main activity to perform a certain action when the service stops

I tried this in my service

```
public void onDestroy() {
    myActivity.getInstance().performAction();
}
```

however this causes timeout service exception as the service doesn't stop except when this action is completed and this action takes a lot of time

how can I get around that . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Service` and `Activity` do not have the same lifecycle. This means your `Service` may find no instance of `YourActivity` when calling `YourActivity.getInstance()`. Your code should resist to that.

And as `performAction()` is a method of `YourActivity`, it would certainly be better to execute it from `YourActivity` instead of executing it from your `Service`.

So you should do as follows I think:

- post a `Message` from your `Service` to `YourActivity` using a `Handler` (more details [on Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [on Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html)) instead of making a direct call to `YourActivity.performAction()` from your `Service`. You would send this message just before calling `Service.stopSelf()` (more details [on stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29)) or why not from an override of this method.
- make `YourActivity` able to handle this message and execute `performAction()` (you can find examples of how to handle messages [here: just Ctrl-F "Handler" in this page](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html)). Execute it in a separate `Thread` to avoid the dreaded "Application Not Responding".

Answer (score 0):

Any action that takes a lot of time needs separated thread. You can look at AsyncTask, Thread, HandlerThread for solution. AsyncTask is probably the best option, since it executes code in own thread. After AsyncTask is finished, callback is called from GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Notifications are used to retrieve the Status from a service.

There are some Threads which might interest you:

[Sending a notification from a service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207269/sending-a-notification-from-a-service-in-android)

or:

[Notify activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111398/android-notify-activity-from-service)

See also the examples in:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html