# Read data from web and display text with intent service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I want an example read data from web and out to textview with intent service.I read this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html but download the file...i want store data to string for use in another function in main activity.Thanks.

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
public String s = "";

public DownloadService() {
super("DownloadService");
}

// Will be called asynchronously be Android
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
Uri data = intent.getData();
String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra("urlpath");

InputStream stream = null;
//FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {

  URL url = new URL(urlPath);
  stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
  //fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
  int next = -1;

  while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
    //fos.write(next);
    s=s+next;
  }
  // Sucessful finished
  result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
```

Comment: Yes...convert this code for string...but how i pass it to main activity?

Comment: My problem is how i send data from intent service to main activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334901/how-to-get-results-from-an-intentservice-back-into-an-activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/android-pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent

Comment: Into main activity i must use getStringExtra with new intent?

Answer (score 0):

As you have append your inputStream from urlPath to "s"

You can access your "s" from your MainActivity using::

```
String data=new DownloadService().s;
```

just instantiate IntentService and access it's parameter with the help of period on the instantiated object.