# How to get value from intentservice on android?

Tags: android

How to get value  from intentservice ? I set a int named count on intentservice
to calculate execution time and I want to get this count value from intentservice , how to do it ?

Comment: One way is you can use a broadcast receiver to send data back to your activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get results from an IntentService back into an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334901/how-to-get-results-from-an-intentservice-back-into-an-activity)