# Pass Activity context in onCreate method

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I need to pass the activity context to my service as soon as the activity is being constructed. Here is my code:

```
public class myService extends Service
{
    private AppCompatActivity activity;

    public void setActivity(AppCompatActivity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
}

public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // ... some things are being executed and myService is being bound
        mService.setActivity(this);
    }
}
```

I get `NullPointerException` as - I suppose - the `myActivity` class is still being constructed and the reference cannot be passed. How can I make Android run this method after `onCreate`? I found some solutions for Java involving factory pattern but I'm not sure how can I use it, if I can use it in my case at all.

Comment: what is mService, is it intantiated

Comment: also we dont use passing of context to do work on the ui thread we use broadcast Intents

Comment: Is it a big issue when we do it the other way? The whole application is already wrote this way and I'm not sure I would be able to force such change all by myself.

Comment: sorry no its not, its just the way I learned from a book. You can do it however you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is a Context by itself. So if you need the `Context` only, you can just call `this` in your `Service`class.

Alternatively, you should pass the `Activity` to the service before starting it. Make sure you pass the `Activity` after calling `super.onCreate(bundle);`

However, you should not manipulate your `Activity` or it's views from a `Service`. A better way is **notifying** your `Activity` from your `Service`.

[Notify activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111398/notify-activity-from-service/4112657#4112657)

Edit: Observer pattern

Create a new class called NotificationCenter.java

```
public class NotificationCenter {

    private static int totalEvents = 1;

    public static final int updateActivity = totalEvents++;
    // you can add more events
    // public static final int anotherEvent = totalEvents++;

    private final SparseArray<ArrayList<Object>> observers = new SparseArray<>();
    private final SparseArray<ArrayList<Object>> removeAfterBroadcast = new SparseArray<>();
    private final SparseArray<ArrayList<Object>> addAfterBroadcast = new SparseArray<>();

    private int broadcasting = 0;

    public interface NotificationCenterDelegate {
        void didReceivedNotification(int id, Object... args);
    }

    private static volatile NotificationCenter Instance = null;

    public static NotificationCenter getInstance() {
        NotificationCenter localInstance = Instance;
        if (localInstance == null) {
            synchronized (NotificationCenter.class) {
                localInstance = Instance;
                if (localInstance == null) {
                    Instance = localInstance = new NotificationCenter();
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }

    public void postNotificationName(int id, Object... args) {
        broadcasting++;
        ArrayList<Object> objects = observers.get(id);
        if (objects != null && !objects.isEmpty()) {
            for (int a = 0; a < objects.size(); a++) {
                Object obj = objects.get(a);
                ((NotificationCenterDelegate) obj).didReceivedNotification(id, args);
            }
        }
        broadcasting--;
        if (broadcasting == 0) {
            if (removeAfterBroadcast.size() != 0) {
                for (int a = 0; a < removeAfterBroadcast.size(); a++) {
                    int key = removeAfterBroadcast.keyAt(a);
                    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = removeAfterBroadcast.get(key);
                    for (int b = 0; b < arrayList.size(); b++) {
                        removeObserver(arrayList.get(b), key);
                    }
                }
                removeAfterBroadcast.clear();
            }
            if (addAfterBroadcast.size() != 0) {
                for (int a = 0; a < addAfterBroadcast.size(); a++) {
                    int key = addAfterBroadcast.keyAt(a);
                    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = addAfterBroadcast.get(key);
                    for (int b = 0; b < arrayList.size(); b++) {
                        addObserver(arrayList.get(b), key);
                    }
                }
                addAfterBroadcast.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public void addObserver(Object observer, int id) {
        if (broadcasting != 0) {
            ArrayList<Object> arrayList = addAfterBroadcast.get(id);
            if (arrayList == null) {
                arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                addAfterBroadcast.put(id, arrayList);
            }
            arrayList.add(observer);
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<Object> objects = observers.get(id);
        if (objects == null) {
            observers.put(id, (objects = new ArrayList<>()));
        }
        if (objects.contains(observer)) {
            return;
        }
        objects.add(observer);
    }

    public void removeObserver(Object observer, int id) {
        if (broadcasting != 0) {
            ArrayList<Object> arrayList = removeAfterBroadcast.get(id);
            if (arrayList == null) {
                arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                removeAfterBroadcast.put(id, arrayList);
            }
            arrayList.add(observer);
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<Object> objects = observers.get(id);
        if (objects != null) {
            objects.remove(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

Then make your `Activities` look like this, you receive messages from the `Service` in `didReceivedNotification()`

```
public class YourActivity implements NotificationCenter.NotificationCenterDelegate {

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        NotificationCenter.getInstance().removeObserver(this, NotificationCenter.updateActivity);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        NotificationCenter.getInstance().addObserver(this, NotificationCenter.updateActivity);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void didReceivedNotification(int id, Object... args) {
        if (id == NotificationCenter.updateActivity) {
            // do something with your activity, your service called this
        }
    }
}
```

Finally send messages in your `Service` to all the `Activities` which are listening:

```
NotificationCenter.getInstance().postNotificationName(NotificationCenter.updateActivity, optionalData);
```

Which is very nice, you don't have to pass Activity instances.

**NotificationCenter source is from Telegram.**

Comment: No, I need specifically context of current activities. As user changes pages in the app the service's reaction should change. Does it mean I can set a starting activity and then before every intent.startActivity() just call the setActivity() method?

Comment: Yes, make sure that your `Service` has the inited `Activity` and then actually run the `Service`.

Comment: Oh, you mean I should pass the context before starting the Service, not the Activity? So the first step is to set the activity, next start the service, and when activity changes another context should be passed and the service restarted? Anyway I'll take a look at the notification approach.

Comment: Exactly! You should do that to prevent the `NullpointerException`

Comment: So I definitly need to give a try to the notifications. I have one service that is being started as soon as the app pops up and runs all the time in background. It basically keeps TCP connection opened and should process incoming packets and update activities, that's why I needed the context.

Comment: Sorry for two comments in a row but is it what I'm looking for? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Comment: Allright, you can also just set the new Activity without restarting the service. I also have some nice observer code for you which might be even better to update Activities.

Comment: Great! As I don't now really much about Notifications yet it's all the same for me to work with them or with your observer code. Where could I find it? On what conditions could I use it?

Comment: Looks great. Can it work the other way around too? I mean notify the Service from Activity?

Comment: Yes, off course. Implement the delegate, and put addObserver in your service, after that call postNotificationName in Activity.

Comment: So I get a little problem with your code. I can't really receive anything in Service. Service class doesn't have any onPause() and onResume() method so I wasn't able to override them. Instead I added addBoserver() method to class constructor but this doesn't work as well. The method didReceiveNotification() isn't called even once.

Comment: It should work. You can email me and we can see what we can do okay?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myService extends Service
{
 public static myActivity activity;

 public static void setActivity(myActivity activity)
 {
     this.activity = activity;
 }
 public void useActivityExample()
{
  myService.myActivity.update();
 }
}

public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       // ... some things are being executed and myService is being bound
      mService.setActivity(getActivity());
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't use myActivity as the activity type in myService as I want to use multiple custom Activities and they would not fit. Also getActivity() cannot be resolved.

Comment: sorry it is not get Activity it is actually getContext, or myActivity.this