# Service with listeners in Android

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I want to implement an Android Service that periodically downloads data and notifies various listener activities that the data has been updated.

There seems to be various way of communicating with a Service. What's the simplest and best way to do the above? A code example or a tutorial will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service/3197456#3197456) to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the EarthquakeViewer samples from http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html.

It shows how to use an `AlarmManager` in the Chapter 9 samples.

Comment: +1 Using a BroadcastReceiver seems to be the easiest way. If no one post a code example I might give it a go next week.

Comment: All the best.  All those example projects are well worth looking at.  If you buy his book it makes it all much clearer as well... and no I don't get kick backs lol.