# sending data to and from a droid querying remote db server

Tags: android, client

What is the best way to pull data from a DB server using android?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to Create a [REST based API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) on the server, and have the API send back JSON, or XML

[here is a related Question from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service)

Another newer approach is to use CouchOne for Android, [information is here](http://www.couchone.com/android)