# How do we interact with a Local Service running in an android application

Tags: android, aidl

I have created a local service .. now how do i access data that gets updated in it or how do i communicate with it ?

Comment: Here is a previous answer with an example of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service/3197456#3197456

Comment: hi.... my actual requirement includes data changing in the service in a regular time interval...that time i want the activity to get updated too... Can i use the same concept??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of Handler and Message classes.