# Android Service + ResultReceiver pattern for RESTful web services

Tags: android, rest, service

With regards to REST operations on Android, I guess most will have seen how [Google I/O App 2010](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) (not 2011!) uses a IntentService + ResultReceiver pattern.

Now I'm wondering the rationale behind clearing the reference to the Activity in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance for Google I/O App.

```
    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        // Clear any strong references to this Activity, we'll reattach to
        // handle events on the other side.
        mState.mReceiver.clearReceiver();
        return mState;
    }
```

My understanding is that [onRetainNoNConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance())  will only be invoked as a result of a configuration change. If so, will clearing the reference to the receiver in onPause(), as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service/3197456#3197456), be better?

Another question I have with regards to this: assuming I were to forget to clear the reference to the activity in onPause()/onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), can I say that as long as my Activity is not destroyed (meaning it is active, paused, or stopped), onReceiveResult() will still be called and my Activity updated?