# Activity wait for Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, wait

**What I'm trying to do**

---

Hello Guys, I'm trying to create a SplashScreen which starts a Service over an Intent. After the Service is started to Activity(SplashScreen) should wait until it receive an Intent from my Service.

**Question**

---

What do I need to do, that my Activity waits until it received the Intent from my Service. It would be nice if you could provide me a good tutorial or some code-snippets.
Down here you find the Code of my SplashScreen.

**Code**

---

```
package de.stepforward;

import de.stepforward.service.VideoService;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        // Sagt dem Video-Service das er beginnen soll die
        // Videos herunter zu laden
        Intent LoadVideos = new Intent(this, VideoService.class);
        LoadVideos.putExtra("VIDEO_SERVICE", "start");
        startService(LoadVideos);

        // In this thread I want that it waits for my Intent
        // and than it goes to the next Activity
        Thread splashThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while (waited < 3000) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                    final Intent Showvideo = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                                                        ChannelTest.class);
                    startActivity(Showvideo);
                }
            }
        };
        splashThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your architecture should look like :

**INTENT_CST**

---

```
String START_INIT_ACTION = "your.package.name.START_INIT";
String INIT_ENDED_ACTION = "your.package.name.INIT_ENDED";
```

**SplashActivity**

---

In onCreate:

```
startService(new Intent(START_INIT_ACTION)
```

In onResume:
If you choose to send a broadcast in your service :

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    //implement onChange()},
    new IntentFilter(INIT_ENDED_ACTION));
```

In onPause, unregister your receiver to free memory

**LoadingService**

---

Extend AsyncTask to do your background stuff. In onPostExecute, 2 options :

```
startActivity(new Intent(...)) // as your doing in your post
```

or

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(INIT_ENDED_ACTION)); stopSelf();
```

**Your manifest**

---

Declare the service LoadingService with an `IntentFilter` with an `<action name="your.package.name.START_INIT"/>`

Answer (score 1):

See this link it might be helpful for you. You can monitor your service state from your activity.

[Restful API service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service/3197456#3197456)

Answer (score 0):

starting a service does not affect foreground screen .so launch splashscreen and start service , as you are doing right now . do operations in service, after that start new activity form service itself .

Comment: ah good idea, but isn't it possible, that the splashscreen waits for the Intent? After that the Activity gets started over the SplashScreen =)