# Android: Thread still Running forever although the Service already destroy

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have try build a android application that use a thread inside a service, the service and the thread run with well, but when i stop and destroy the service, the thread still live, so when i run again the application there are 2 thread in the application, so i wannt to know how i can destroy the thread.
anybody can help me to solve the problem ?

here my service class :

```
public class MyService extends Service{
    Handler handler;
    static String toast_msg;
    Thread t;
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
       /* Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    //Note: You can start a new thread and use it for long background processing from here.*/
        toast_msg = "Horas";
        super.onStart(intent, startId);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast_msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

         handler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast_msg,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try { 
                        t.sleep(5000);
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Horas",
                        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        //t.interrupt();
        handler.removeCallbacks(t);
        super.onDestroy();
        t.currentThread().interrupt();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try { 
                    if(flag){//here add a flag
                      return;
                    }
                    t.sleep(5000);
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Horas",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    //t.interrupt();
    handler.removeCallbacks(t);
    super.onDestroy();
    flag = false;//here set flag to false
}
```

Comment: That does indeed solve his immediate problem, but I've proposed what I think would be a better approach, below :)

Comment: it's work and run well, i thinks this helpfull for other like me, thank you

Comment: The flag variable is used on two different threads, so all access to it should be synchronized to guarantee correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Service or IntentService instead, as these provide better management of threads, pausing, restarting etc.

See the Android [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) documentation, or this other [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intent-service) question and answer session. There's not much call to be kicking off your own threads these days, as there's better threading/service management features provided by the Android API/SDKs.

These  are much more stable, optimised, and (in my opinion) neater and cleaner to use than spinning up a raw thread and trying to manage it yourself, especially if you're not catering for your app suddenly being killed because the battery went flat or the user doing something unexpected.

Comment: The service _(except IntentService, but OP uses started service)_ runs on the UI thread by default, so creating a new thread is totally acceptable.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
"Note that services, like other application objects, **run in the main thread of their hosting process** . This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, **it should spawn its own thread** in which to do that work."