# Use service or intent service?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-intentservice

I don't know which of these methods are suited for my needs. I need to add a background service to my application that

1. Opens a server socket
2. Wait for a socket connection from a client
3. Once socket connection is made, indefinitely listen for messages sent through the client

The application has no activities and is essentially 2 services (1 that exists for something else, and 1 that I described above)

Should I extend service or intent service? I assume I'll need to make threads within either of the classes as to not block other code execution in the other service?

Comment: Please check below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intent-service

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> 2) Wait for a socket connection from a client 3) Once socket connection is made, indefinitely listen for messages sent through the client.

It's better for you to extend `Service` for this operation. `IntentService` is a service class which can't handles waiting task, but `Service` can handles it. `IntentService` always do its job impatiently.

Comment: If I use Service class and use threads as well, this will not block other code execution in another service, correct?

Comment: Correct. A `Service` class never blocks other thread and code execution.