# What is the difference between service, intentService in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, intentservice

What is the difference between `Service` and an `IntentService`  in Android?

What is the difference between `AsyncTask` and an `IntentService`  in Android?

Answer (score 35):

**1. Difference between Service and IntentService**

**Service**: It is the base class for the Android services, that you can extend for creating any service.
Since the service run inside the UI thread, it requires that you create a working thread for executing its work.

**IntentService**: it is a subclass of `Service`, that simplifies your work. It works already in a working thread, and can receive asynchronous requests. So, you don't need to create it manually, or to worry about synchronization. You can simply extend it and override the method:

```
onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
```

where you can manage all the incoming requests.

Taking a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService), you can see in details what the `IntentService` do for you:

- Creates a default worker thread that executes all intents delivered to `onStartCommand()` separate from your application's main thread.
- Creates a work queue that passes one intent at a time to your `onHandleIntent()` implementation, so you never have to worry about multi-threading.
- Stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you never have to call `stopSelf()`.
- Provides default implementation of `onBind()` that returns null.
- Provides a default implementation of `onStartCommand()` that sends the intent to the work queue and then to your `onHandleIntent()` implementation.

So, if you need more control you can use the `Service` class, but often for a simple service the best solution is the `IntentService`.

**2. Difference between AsyncTask and Service**

They are two different concepts.

**Service:** can be intended as an Activity with no interface. It is suitable for long-running operations.

**AsyncTask:** is a particular class that wraps a working thread (performing background operations), facilitating the interaction with the UI Thread, without managing threads or handlers directly.

Comment: There are nice explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15772151/1533670

Comment: This explanation is nice but if you could go into some more detail on AsyncTask (especially the downsides) it would be better.

Comment: There is quite a lot to say about `AsyncTask`, and there is the documentation for that. I tried to keep it short just pointing out the differences with the `Service`