# Android Service running in background data loss

Tags: android, sockets, service, udp, server

I have a UDP Server/Client running in background with Service, these are my operations:

- I launch the app
- The Service starts
- I close the app but the Service is running in background (this is
  what I want)
- I send udp message and the phone receives correctly and answer me
- I don't send messages for about 5 minutes
- I send message, my phone doesn't answer me
- I try to send another message again, my phone now answer

How could it happen? My App seems to sleep and wake up when I send the first message but it could answer only the second or sometimes I need 4-5 messages before get an answer, maybe is this latency or other?

If I flood my App it always will answer me correctly, but if I don't send messages for an amount of time it will cause the problem.

I want my App answer me everytime, even if the app is closed or the phone is locked.

This is my code:

```
public class UDPListenerService extends Service {

    DatagramSocket socket;
    private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen = true;
    Thread UDPBroadcastThread;

    private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent() throws Exception {
        try {
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);

                while (true) {

                    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
                    System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                    InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                    int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                    String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
                    sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                    serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                    receiveData = new byte[1024];

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }    

    void startListenForUDPBroadcast() {
        UDPBroadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
                        listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent();
                    }
                    //if (!shouldListenForUDPBroadcast) throw new ThreadDeath();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("UDP", "no longer listening for UDP broadcasts cause of error " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        UDPBroadcastThread.start();
    }    

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        shouldRestartSocketListen = true;
        startListenForUDPBroadcast();
        Log.i("UDP", "Service started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopListen();
    }
    void stopListen() {
        shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: use WakeLock & IntentService

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad How can I use WakeLock and why IntentService? I post another question about Service or IntenetService and they answered me to use service,  see my question

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad I don't think I need to use IntentService, I can read inside Google Documentation that START_STICKY allow me to keep alway alive my Service. I need to know why my thread wake up after some requests

Comment: just saw listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent() is consuming Exception and throwing exception as well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your app stops is because the service is put to sleep by the system. Maybe you need use the bindService() method in the calling activity.

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html for more info about the methods and the lifecycles of services.