# Implementing Geo-fencing - Receiving geo-fences transition events when the app is not running

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, android-geofence

I'm implementing Geo-fences. It works quite well, but their transition events only get trigger when the app is in background or foreground. I have an IntentService that receives the geo-fences transitions events, but my problem is that this intent service only receives updates if the app is running.

The implementation has an standard LocationService for managing the geo-fences by the app when is running, then an IntentService that gets notified by the OS when a geo-fence transition is detected.

Have you got any solution to receive transitions even when the app is not running at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution as per [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#Troubleshooting).

The recommended min radius should be between `100` to `150` metres, specially if you are using `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` or `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` in your location request.

The issue I had was that I was saving the geo-fences to the device with a very small radius (e.g 20 metres) in which case the device didn't detect the geo-fence transition events at all when the app is not running (not in background and foreground).

Answer (score 1):

[Intent service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is supposed to start a worker thread, process whatever you plan it to do and then close itself. In your case when the app is running the service basically spawns, does work and then shuts itself down.

From the android docs

> the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

To solve this you might want to [create](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) your own service implementation via extending the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class.

[Checkout diff between Intent Service and Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772151/2745762)

P.S : If you provided some code which you have tried one can directly show you whats exactly is not making your code run when the app is not running.