# How to stop service the service when android app has been closed

Tags: android, performance

I am developing a app where I need to updated my values every 15 min.
For that i am using services.I came across different types of services.
Like for long running services we use simple service and,
          for interacting for other components we use bind service,
          foreground service. etc....

My situation is like i need to run the service for every 15 min 
when my app is open and stop the service when my app is closed

I have tried with bind service using 
http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/
but i am unable to do that,I am unable to run the service every 15 min can any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are starting the service from the activity right ? and the service is running in the background always. when the activity stops then you want to stop the service ?

Comment: Your title and question have confused me. Your title says, you want to know how to stop the service and your question says you want to know how to start service in every 15 mins. Please tell me exactly what you want ?

Comment: @sagar yes you right.I want to stop the service,when my gets closed

Comment: I have given my answer. please check it.

Comment: @varun I want to start the service when my app is opened and stop the service when my is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the service when your app starts, start it in onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);

}
```

To stop the service, you can implement the code in 3 different methods namely, onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy().

Calling stopService() in onPause() will stop the service as soon as some other event happens on your device like a phone call, which is not best way to stop since the user will return back to the Activity immediately as soon as the call finishes.

Calling stopService() in onDestroy() is also not the best solution because onDestroy is not called in all the ways a user can close an Android app.

Therefore, the best way to stop the service is by calling stopService() in the onStop() method as shown below.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
    stopService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer how can i start the service in separate  thread

Comment: You'll just need the context of the Activity to start service from a separate thread. Rest all implementation of Service will be the same.

Comment: Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
      
            getTimestamp();
            }
        });
        t.start(); can i use this way

Comment: Yes, you can. Start the service from the run() method by help of Activity's context.

Comment: Hey I am unable to stop the service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108018/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-varun-kumar).

Comment: I've replied to you in the chat session you created above. Please do have a look.

Comment: Hi varun i have replied in chat

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, just read your reply in chat. Please post your code where you are starting and stopping the Service along with your Service class code. To post your code, edit your question above and post it there. If you are getting any errors then do post you log details.

Comment: Also post your code where you start your Service in every 15 mins.

Comment: can you join me in chat

Comment: I've replied you in the chat. Please do have a look.

Comment: Varun i have also replied can you check it once

Comment: Sanjeev. please check my reply in chat.

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, I've replied in chat. Please do have a look.

Comment: HI Varun Thanks. will you be on chat

Comment: Sure, will be there in a second.

Comment: HI Varun Can you come to chat

Comment: HI, Varun can you come to chat

Comment: Hi, Sanjeev. Sure, tell me the time and I'll be there.

Comment: will you come at 1:30 PM after lunch

Comment: Sure, I'll be there.

Comment: HI Varun can you come on chat

Comment: Hi Varun can you please come online

Comment: Hi Sanjeev. Sorry for late reply. I just came on StackOverflow after about 2 weeks. Sure, I can come online today. Just let me know the time and I'll be there.

Comment: Hi varun , Can you come online now

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, I'm online now.

Comment: HI Varun Can you come online

Comment: HI Varun, Can you come now?

Comment: This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.

Comment: Yes. You need to create a new question. Then only a new chat room can be created.

Comment: If you've already created a question, just give me the link here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112036/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-varun-kumar).

Comment: Hey Now I think we can have chat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop service when your activity is closing then you have to implement the code inside [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()).

Below is an example-

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
    stopService(intent);
}
```

This will your stop your service.

Unless you don't call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) in the activity or you explicitly stop the app the [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) don't gets called and your service will run even your calling activity is onPause (in background).

Similarly if you want to start your service  activity start you implement in onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

let me know if it help your problem .

Comment: suppose if i am in activity A where i have started my service and if i move to different activity say B, will the service get stopped or will it be running?

Comment: No your service still run if you go to different activity .

Comment: Can we implement Intentservice here

Comment: i would not suggest using it .(The IntentService cannot run tasks in parallel. Hence all the consecutive intents will go into the message queue for the worker thread and will execute sequentially.) here is a link for your reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108019/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-sagar-nayak).