# Google maps keeps hanging after moving 5 kms in in my android app?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi i am android developer with just 3 months experience.I am developing a taxi app which needs to send user's `latlong` to server through `webservice`.I almost completed my project.But now i facing a new problem,I wrote the `webservice` in service class and call it from my activity,my problem is "the touch become irresponsive after the user moves to 5 km and then crashed like app is not responding".What i need is i want to send user's `latlong` for morethan 100 kms.i had added my logcat to show errors

I tested on two device.

1.First,In 1gb ram mobiles it crashes at 5 kms.
2.Second,In 2gb ram mobiles,it crashes at 30 kms.

Please anybody help, otherwise i will be fired from my office.

My acticity code with map is :

```
public class Mapforcalculation extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener {

                private LinearLayout lay_start_ride_lay;
                private Switch waiting,ac;
                private boolean act,dateforrow;
                private  long starttime,diffrence,secs,waitingtimefl,resultwait;
                private int luggage_chage;
                private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
                private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
                private Location Mylocation;
                private  String cust_name,Customer_Adress,custom_mobile,Ride_id,drive_id,vehic_id,s,url,finalAddsres,resendasy;
                 double responseeein,aa_actualfare,waitTimeFrae,Min_KM_ride,minimumFare,rateperkm,acrateperkm,nightminimrate,nightadd_minmrate,Acnightadd_mrate;
                private double  nightFare=0, addRatePerMinit=0,night_time_frm_hrs,night_time_to_hrs;
                private long attr;
                private double A_ActualFare,start_lat,start_long;
                private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
                private Location location;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.driver_with_map_wait_cust);
                      keepScreenOn();
                     buildGoogleApiClient();
                    setLocationRequestMap();
                 }
               private void keepScreenOn() {
                    try {
              getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
               mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                            .build();
                }
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    /*new Calculationtask().execute();*/
                    Dayornight();
                    gettingdistanec();
                    rideEndVolly(aa_actualfare);

                }

                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            Log.i("connected","connected");

                    startLocationUpdates();
             Intent intent = new Intent(this,Serviceafterstartbutton.class);         
                    intent.putExtra("Ride_id",Ride_id);
                    this.startService(intent);
                }
           @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {   }
            @Override
                protected void onResume() {
                    super.onResume();
                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                         buildGoogleApiClient();
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

                    }
                    if (mGoogleMap == null) {
                        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
             mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
                    mGoogleMap.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
                    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    mGoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }

                    Log.i("onmsppreddy","onmappreddy");
                }
                private void Dayornight() {
                  long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
                    String dateforrowwww = dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
                    long datee= Long.parseLong(dateforrowwww);
                    Log.d("datee", " url :" + datee);
                    if(datee >= 5 && datee < 22){
                        /*dateforrow="Day";*/
                        dateforrow=true;
                        Log.d("datefrw", " url :" + dateforrow);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dateforrow=false;
                    }
                }
                private void  gettingdistanec() {
           final String url = Api_url.url_link +"dist_km.php?driverid="+ drive_id+"&vehicle_id="+vehic_id+"&ride_id="+Ride_id;
                    Log.d("URL_P", url);

                    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try{
                                String rresponseee=response.getString("km");
                                Log.d("OVER", "km : " + response);

                                if(rresponseee!= null) {
                                    responseeein =  Double.valueOf(rresponseee);
                                    calculatefinalfare(responseeein);
                                }

                               }catch(Exception e){
                                Log.d("OVERRR", "errorr : " + e);                }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });
                    setRetyMethod(request);
                }
                private void setRetyMethod(JsonObjectRequest request) {
                    try {
                        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 3, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Mapforcalculation.this);
                    requestQueue.add(request);
                }
            protected void startLocationUpdates() {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
                }

                private void setLocationRequestMap() {
                   mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
                    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
             }
           private void getCurrentLocation() {
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    //Creating a location object
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                     location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                }
        private String getAddressbylatlong(double start_lat, double start_lon) {
                    Geocoder geocoder;
                    List<Address> addresses = null;
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                    String address = null; // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                    String city = null;
                    String state = null;
         try {
                        // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(start_lat, start_lon, 1);
                        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String finalAddress;
                    try {
                        if (address != null) {
                            finalAddress = address.trim() + city.trim() + state.trim();
                            finalAddress = finalAddress.replace(" ", "");
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                    return finalAddress;
                }
            @Override
                protected void onDestroy() {
                    super.onDestroy();
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
                }
            }
```

My service class is

```
    public class Serviceafterstartbutton extends Service implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static Boolean serviceRunning = false;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private String vechi_id;
    private String drivi_ID;
    private String Rideid;
    private Location mYLocation;
    private Timer locTimwe;
    private Context appContext;
    private boolean tthreadnew=true;
    private int startId22;

    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("onConn", "location");
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //Location Request

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


        Log.i("ongoogleapiinlstser", "null is false");

//        this.stopSelf();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


    }

    public void createlocation() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000); // Update location every second

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

         startId22=startId;
        appContext=getBaseContext();//Get the context here


/*createlocation();*/
        serviceRunning = true;
        Rideid=intent.getStringExtra("Ride_id");

        final CarLoginSession carLoginSession = new CarLoginSession(getApplicationContext());
        final HashMap<String, String> car_hm = carLoginSession.isGetCarDetails();
        vechi_id = car_hm.get(CarLoginSession.IS_GET_VEHICLE_ID);

        //Driver login Session
        DriverLoginSession driverLoginSession = new DriverLoginSession(getApplicationContext());
        final HashMap<String, String> driv_hm = driverLoginSession.isGetDriverDetails();
        drivi_ID = driv_hm.get(DriverLoginSession.IS_DIV_ID);



        /*executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getCurrentLocation();
                update_aftr_strt(mYLocation);

                Log.i("ongoogleapi","thresds");
            }
        },10,5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/

        Log.d("onConn", "start_connected");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    void showToast(final String text) {
        if (null != appContext) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(appContext, ""+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    class mythreadclass implements Runnable{
        int service_id;
        mythreadclass(int service_id){
            this.service_id=service_id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this){
                while (tthreadnew){
                    try {
                        getCurrentLocation();
                        Log.i("ongoogleapi","thresds");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {


        //Creating a location object
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            mYLocation = location;
            update_aftr_strt(mYLocation);


            //moving the map to location

        }
    }


    private String getAddressbylatlong(double start_lat, double start_lon) {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String address = null; // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = null;
        String state = null;

        try {
            // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(start_lat, start_lon, 1);
            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String finalAddress;
        try {
            if (address != null) {
                finalAddress = address.trim() + city.trim() + state.trim();
                finalAddress = finalAddress.replace(" ", "");
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return finalAddress;
    }

    private void update_aftr_strt(Location mYLocation) {

        double start_Lat=0;

        double start_lon=0;
        String addsres = null;
        try {
            start_Lat = mYLocation.getLatitude();
            start_lon = mYLocation.getLongitude();
            addsres = getAddressbylatlong(start_Lat, start_lon);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//            getLocationMethods();
        }

        final String url = Api_url.url_link + "current_location_ride.php?latitude=" + start_Lat +
                "&longitude=" + start_lon + "&driverid=" + drivi_ID + "&loc_address=" + addsres + "&vehicle_id=" + vechi_id + "&ride_id=" + Rideid;
        Log.d("URL_Pcc", url);

        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("after_Start_loc", response.toString());
                String aftr_atrt_respons = null;


                try {
                    aftr_atrt_respons = response.getString("update");
                    if (aftr_atrt_respons.equals("success")) {
                        showToast("updateaftr start");

                    } else {
                        showToast("update aftr start failed!!");                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                showToast("noresponsefromserver");

            }
        });
        setRetyMethod(request);
    }

    private void setRetyMethod(JsonObjectRequest request) {
        try {
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 3, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Serviceafterstartbutton.this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Thread thread=new Thread(new mythreadclass(startId22));
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tthreadnew =false;


    }
}
```

my error is:`

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 32 byte allocation with 8 free bytes and 8B until OO at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:174at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:247 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:190) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.executeCommand(Daemons.java:341) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:279) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

`

Comment: you are using a lot of ur main UI thread, keep things on Thread.

Comment: @W4R10CK thank you for ur answer......i am using these method only once in oncreate.the method which runs continuosly is written in service.can u explain me some more,please?i am new to development ...how to less use ui thread?

Answer (score 0):

//You can Create a radius for 100km and and just hide those markers if didnt lie in the 100km //

```
private void drawCircle(LatLng point){

            // Instantiating CircleOptions to draw a circle around the marker
            CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();

            // Specifying the center of the circle
            circleOptions.center(point);

            // Radius of the circle
            circleOptions.radius(20);

            // Border color of the circle
            circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);

            // Fill color of the circle
            circleOptions.fillColor(0x30ff0000);

            // Border width of the circle
            circleOptions.strokeWidth(2);

            // Adding the circle to the GoogleMap
            googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

        }
```

//Now calculate distance of patriclar latlong and and current position  by this //
// The computed distance is stored in results[0].
//If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1].
//If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].

```
float[] results = new float[1];
```

Location.distanceBetween(oldPosition.latitude, oldPosition.longitude,
                newPosition.latitude, newPosition.longitude, results);

//Check if the distance is greater than radius then show (>100km)
Show on Map

Answer (score 0):

You need to use thread inside the service as [it run on main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice)

your service can hang UI

remember the tasks that you need to perform one time should be called in oncreate method not onstartcommend method like

`mGoogleApiClient.connect();`

should be called in oncreate and don't use synchronized  method in service

**i have made few changes in your service class**

you are **not using location updates** ( u always get last known location after thread wake up from sleep ( there is no need to create thread just for this we already have location updates, you will get user updates location

you are also **not using updated location** in your activity

**Note:** once your work is done you also need to stop this service as well.

```
public class Serviceafterstartbutton extends Service implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static Boolean serviceRunning = false;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private String vechi_id;
    private String drivi_ID;
    private String Rideid;
    private Location mYLocation;
    private Timer locTimwe;
    private Context appContext;
    private boolean tthreadnew=true;
    private int startId22;

    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("onConn", "location");
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //Location Request

        buildGoogleApiClient();

          startId22=startId;
        appContext=getBaseContext();//Get the context here


/*createlocation();*/
        serviceRunning = true;

        final CarLoginSession carLoginSession = new CarLoginSession(getApplicationContext());
        final HashMap<String, String> car_hm = carLoginSession.isGetCarDetails();
        vechi_id = car_hm.get(CarLoginSession.IS_GET_VEHICLE_ID);

        //Driver login Session
        DriverLoginSession driverLoginSession = new DriverLoginSession(getApplicationContext());
        final HashMap<String, String> driv_hm = driverLoginSession.isGetDriverDetails();
        drivi_ID = driv_hm.get(DriverLoginSession.IS_DIV_ID);

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();



        Log.i("ongoogleapiinlstser", "null is false");

//        this.stopSelf();
    }

    protected void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


    }

    public void createlocation() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000); // Update location every second

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {



        Rideid=intent.getStringExtra("Ride_id");

        /*executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getCurrentLocation();
                update_aftr_strt(mYLocation);

                Log.i("ongoogleapi","thresds");
            }
        },10,5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/

        Log.d("onConn", "start_connected");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    void showToast(final String text) {
        if (null != appContext) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(appContext, ""+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    class mythreadclass implements Runnable{
        int service_id;
        mythreadclass(int service_id){
            this.service_id=service_id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this){
                while (tthreadnew){
                    try {
                        getCurrentLocation();
                        Log.i("ongoogleapi","thresds");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {


        //Creating a location object
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            mYLocation = location;
            update_aftr_strt(mYLocation);


            //moving the map to location

        }
    }


    private String getAddressbylatlong(double start_lat, double start_lon) {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String address = null; // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = null;
        String state = null;

        try {
            // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(start_lat, start_lon, 1);
            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String finalAddress;
        try {
            if (address != null) {
                finalAddress = address.trim() + city.trim() + state.trim();
                finalAddress = finalAddress.replace(" ", "");
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return finalAddress;
    }

    private void update_aftr_strt(Location mYLocation) {

        double start_Lat=0;

        double start_lon=0;
        String addsres = null;
        try {
            start_Lat = mYLocation.getLatitude();
            start_lon = mYLocation.getLongitude();
            addsres = getAddressbylatlong(start_Lat, start_lon);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//            getLocationMethods();
        }

        final String url = Api_url.url_link + "current_location_ride.php?latitude=" + start_Lat +
                "&longitude=" + start_lon + "&driverid=" + drivi_ID + "&loc_address=" + addsres + "&vehicle_id=" + vechi_id + "&ride_id=" + Rideid;
        Log.d("URL_Pcc", url);

        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("after_Start_loc", response.toString());
                String aftr_atrt_respons = null;


                try {
                    aftr_atrt_respons = response.getString("update");
                    if (aftr_atrt_respons.equals("success")) {
                        showToast("updateaftr start");

                    } else {
                        showToast("update aftr start failed!!");                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                showToast("noresponsefromserver");

            }
        });
        setRetyMethod(request);
    }

    private void setRetyMethod(JsonObjectRequest request) {
        try {
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 3, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Serviceafterstartbutton.this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            mYLocation = location;
            update_aftr_strt(mYLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {


        // Thread thread=new Thread(new mythreadclass(startId22));
        // thread.start();

        // no need for this thread to create and put in sleep we already have location update that we will get after in every 10 seconds ( 10)

            createlocation();
            getCurrentLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tthreadnew =false;


    }
}
```

Comment: i edited and added my thread class..bt still hanging and same problem

Comment: @lucky update your post according to the change so i can look into the changes

Comment: @Adeel...thank you..i edited and posted my changes..i had included mythread class...

Comment: @lucky i have edited my answer check it, i have made few changes in your service class

Comment: i had added my logcat error.please see that and tell me any suggestions

Comment: @lucky add  android:largeHeap="true" in application tag in your manifest

Comment: i added ,but still app crashes

Comment: @lucky same out of memory exception or different exception, if different post the exception