# On Application Destroy, Android is re-creates the service

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-service

This has been asked so many times, I have seen and applied many answers but nothing seems to be helping here.

This is how i am starting server on application launch

```
startService(new Intent(MavsMainActivity.this, LocationUpdateService.class));
```

**Manifest**

```
<service android:name=".myservices.services.LocationUpdateService"
    android:process=":locationService"
    />
```

When i forcefully closed the application, It triggers the `onCreate()` of service again. I have tried `return START_STICKY` and `return START_NOT_STICKY`, one re-starts the service on `Application onDestroy`, and one restarts it when user relaunch the application after destroying it respectively.

This is my service class, Kindly guide  me how can i keep service running on background even user destroys the application.

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

            if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
                /* min dist for location change, here it is 10 meter */
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();

                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(BACKGROUND_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(20);

            sendOfflineData();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStart Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   return START_STICKY ;

    }
```

Comment: Use IBinder for continue your  background process

Comment: THanks Application is crashing after adding process in Manifest file

Comment: You can't do that. This is Android design. System will restart your service when your app is killed either by system to claim memory or by user itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `IntentService` instead of `Service` why?

> **Service**: The Service runs in background but it runs on the Main Thread of the application.
>
> **IntentService:**  The IntentService runs on a separate worker thread.

On Application Destroy service stop and the restart it if you return `START_STICKY` because its seprate thread but running on Main application thread.

you should `IntentService` and look here for [**details**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, This make things clearer, One Question, not related to this question, will be grateful if you answer it here. I have extends service from IntentService, and it creates 2 additional methods, `onHandleIntent` and a constructor, Do i need to do anything in them, or will it work fine without giving any implementation to these methods.

Comment: In case of IntentService, implement your logic (code) into onHandleIntent method.