# What happens to Application after IntentService is killed because of no requests to it

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-intentservice

I read about [`IntentService`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice) and wonder about it´s lifestyle and effect on  the Android Application. I know when the `IntentService` starts Android first starts the `android.app.Application` by running `onCreate()` . When the `IntentService` running queue is empty the `IntentService` can be killed.
But what happens then to the started `android.app.Application`?

Comment: You just ask out of curiousity, or you are dependent on that state?

Comment: I use the [onesignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com) that have the `IntentService` launching in Android on incoming push messages, Now I try to learn about what´s happening around my app. It´s a programming question I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Application` class is a Singleton and will exist as long as your app's process still exits. The `IntentService` exits on its own once the are no more `Intent`s for it to handle, but that does not mean the app process exits. Read about processes and threads here to get more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html