# Background service to update UI continuously

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background, intentservice

I would like to run a service that gets data from an external sensor and updates the UI **every second** without blocking the main thread. What is the **most efficient** possibility to make it? Thread, IntentService, Service? Or anyting else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solution to your problem probably depends how you are getting data from external sensor.

Comment: I'm getting data via Bluetooth socket. I send a request and I get data.

Comment: Then you already have a thread for this BT socket. Use the same thread and update UI with runOnUiThread as needed.

Comment: No, I don't have a permanent thread. A command looks like

ResetTroubleCodesCommand clear = new ResetTroubleCodesCommand();
clear.run(sock.getInputStream(), sock.getOutputStream());

Then I get the data. So I need to execute these commands in a different thread.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you would post your code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a binded service if you want to update UI regularly and the activity has to access the service method.

[Service vs IntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice)

Check how binded service in android works in this [link](http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use binding service.[Read here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Here are some examples:

1. [example1](http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/).
2. [example2](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-started-bound-services/)

Answer (score 1):

First off-  Services run on the UI thread.  So a service won't fix the problem of blocking the main thread.  Of course getting a sensor reading is quick, so you shouldn't need to worry about it.

What else are you using the data for?  If its only to update the UI, no need for a service.  Just register for sensor events in your activity and update the UI when you get a sensor event.  If you want to do something else, like save the data even when the app is in the background, then you may want to look at Services.

Comment: I have to send requests to get data, so I can't use events.

Answer (score 0):

[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) should be used if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or later.

Comment: I think JobScheduler is not suitable for me, because it's about live data, so I have to update the UI every second.