# How to get an object parameter with Android Service periodically?

Tags: java, android, service, background, period

**My problem is:** I have an application that is monitoring a car in real time.

I connected the car to my phone, make an object from it, but I don't know how to get this object parameters in background in every 1 sec. My first idea was Android Service, but

**How can get a car parameter in every second even the app is killed?**

My car instance:

```
Car myCar = new Car(100) ;
```

Which means my car has a 100% battery, and it's reducing.

*Thank's for your answers! Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, you may want to read up on IntentServices and Broadcast Receivers as a starting point [here](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772151/193467) also provides more depth about using background services.