# Which should I use class for the stopwatch to run in the background. "IntentService" or "service"

Tags: java, android, service, intentservice

what service class should I use for the stopwatch that will run on the background

Which one should I use in terms of performance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use foreground service (with **Service** instead of `IntentService`) in this case.

**Reasons:**

- Android Oreo 8.0 defined **[Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)**. So you will not be guaranteed of service life.
- Your app is also killed in **[Doze mode & Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby)** .
- If you are running a continuous service with a `long thread` & `start-sticky` then your app is being suspected by optimization apps and OS. Your app will be considered battery draining.
- `Intentservice` kills itself when work is done. Whether normal Service fits your requirement where only you have controls of your service.

**Solution:**

As i said **make normal service** as foreground service. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6397754/6891563). That will **notify** user till your **service is running**. And it will not be killed by OS due to any above reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an old question with loads of answers regarding differences between Service and IntentService. Maybe you can find something there.

From personal experience i'd say they are not that much different. Just the way you use them. I would say stick with the one you think fits your application best overall.

[Service vs IntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice)