# Intent Service or Service for multiple file uploading?

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, intentservice

I'm trying to upload multiple files to **firebase** and want to keep uploading even if the app is killed just like google drive.

Should i use `intent-service` or  `service` for this?

Comment: Maybe you should read some of the other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice) here on SO that explain in detail the main differences between Services and Intent Services and that can help you in making a decision

Answer (score 0):

use intent-service as it support longer tasks more than service