# Which android class is recommended for a permanent background process?

Tags: java, android, background-process

I would like to build an android app with a permanent background process. I thought of using a Job, but is there a better class for doing this?

Comment: What have you researched so far? Can you explain which 'background process' could be the solution? BTW, do you know foreground services?

Comment: Have a look at [this documentation of an `IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service). Maybe that's suitable for your requirements.

Comment: Foreground service, probably

Comment: Is there a reason you want permanently access to execute code? There's a reason why manufactures choose to kill apps: they use way too much battery even when closed.

Answer (score 1):

A [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) may be what you're looking for. These always run in the background, however have [many limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) and are often killed by the OS.

If you need your service to (almost) always be alive, it can either be woken up by system intents / notifications, or run as a foreground service (notification is shown to user, but app is almost always active).

From the above link:

> **Foreground**
>
> A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play an audio track. Foreground services must display a Notification. Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't interacting with the app.
>
> **Background**
>
> A background service performs an operation that isn't directly noticed by the user. For example, if an app used a service to compact its storage, that would usually be a background service.

As mentioned in comments, `IntentService` is another option, [here's a comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772151/608312) between it and a normal `Service`. It will however suffer the same restrictions as a normal background service.

For a more accurate answer, I'd suggest editing your question to include what your service needs to do.

Comment: IntentService cannot be started from the background as of Oreo restrictions, best choice would probably be a sticky service that gets restarted on reboot or whenever necessary, if it needs to complete some long running task/work without needing any restarts or such then I would say JobIntentService

Comment: @Brandon Got it. I was including it as a commenter mentioned it, have never used myself. Will update.

Comment: I am trying to develop an app, which permanently executes my code every second. It would also be ok, if it needs root.

Comment: @Venji Foreground service is likely what you're after then!