# Android app : Download/Upload Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

My goal is simple : I am developing an Android app and want to upload files on Google Drive and I also want to be able to read their properties and to download them. So is there a solution out there that doesn't use deprecated JSon objects and that can do it?

- Connect
- Read file properties (date modified)
- Download
- Upload

Thank you.

Comment: FYI : I searched and tried various methods using various libs but to no avail. All I've read so far (execpt in the answer) was using deprecated JSon objects. Don't think I ask this while I didn't search, I'm not that kind of developer. I just need a kick start with Android apps and all I read wasn't including base information for Google Drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the REST API's provided by the [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

For connecting, You can use OAuth 2.0 :
https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth

For detecting whther a file has changed see:
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes

For downloading files, see:
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

For uploading files, see:
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

For info on how to use REST API's in Android correctly, see:

[Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

[Restful API service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/restful-api-service)

Hope this helps.....

Comment: I've seen this one in my research but I lack some base knowledge on how the heck can I know where the file is located?

Comment: This is indeed helpful, sadly it won't allow me to +1 the post. I am still unsure though about an issue where I see "service.getRequestFactory()" in the download portion in warning. It says it is deprecated so I was wondering what was the most up to date version (even though the info comes from developers.google.com).

Thanks again!