# Google Drive Android API tutorial for Download & Upload File

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have gone through Google Drive API Documentation and tried Official Google Drive Demos from Github as well. I couldn't find directly download file from Google Drive to Android Local Storage. There are so many threads on StackOverflow and I tried some but no success yet.
Can someone point me to right direction? Tutorial link or even StackOverflow thread which works?

1. As per my needs Google Drive Android API doesn't provide Download and Upload atleast that's not in documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro
   Documentation shows reading from input stream and writing to it.
2. So I decided to use Google Drive REST API. which clearly states downloading and uploading methods or endpoints.
3. Now the issue is Rest documentation not showing how to authenticate on android and use that authentication to make requests to REST API.

Comment: you need file id to download file from google drive

Comment: Please check updated question. My problem is not with finding File ID.

Comment: You can check this [SO related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13884259/5995040), it is an old post but I think it is still used. Also try reading the [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2dn_3573C3RdlVpU2JBWXdSb3c/edit?usp=sharing) and watching this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) on Dobjanschi's presentation for people learning Android REST client implementation.